# React Native Android: Static Image is not showing in production released apk

Tags: reactjs, react-native, reactjs-flux

I have static image in my react-native app accessing via

```
  <Image source={require("../assets/preview-full-img-title-logo@2x.png")} />
```

in development it is showing well but in production release APK is not showing what can be the reason? I have followed steps mention here.

```
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html
```

Comment: try to assign your image source to a global var like var _logo = require(...) and try again.source ={_logo} Even if it does not work you will have a better implementation.

Comment: Alright need to focus on solution. any other suggestion

Comment: You don't need the @2x in the url. Just do require("../assets/preview-full-img-title-logo.png") But not sure if thats is related to your issue though. Worth a try :)

Comment: Not only this image but every image that i am using in the app, is no getting load in production, just static image not dynamic

Comment: i've encountered a similar issue and came finally up to assign "width" and "height" properties within the <Image>-Tag and also in the style-sheet. Without this no image was drawn in production-apk on some devices (not all)

Comment: @itinancei have checked it by giving inline style as well as in styles like this       <Image source={require("../assets/tick-mark.png")} style={[styles.addIcon],{height:45,width:45}}/> but it is not working

Comment: Is is something about putting images into the src folder. do i need to put image android/src/main/assets.

Comment: @hasseio i am still unable to resolve

Comment: Build a tiny app that shows the problem, and then publish it on github or bitbucket. Without a larger set of code, its difficult to debug this problem.

Comment: Are you using data binding in your app?

Comment: you mean bind(this) or two way binding. i am using both the way that react applied

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the command that did it for me:

`react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js \ --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle \ --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/`

[take a look at github issue>](https://github.com/tkporter/react-native-fabric-twitterkit/issues/1#issuecomment-244621317)

Comment: it gives me `error: option '--bundle-output' missing`

Comment: deleting both "\" works form me : `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/`

Comment: Version 61.5. This command creates folder and copy images. But once I close the terminal (and disconnect the cable) and I run the app again the images are not visible anymore. I use <Image source="./assets/image.png" /> ... Ideas?

Comment: can you please check the link in your answer again. is it correct?

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9451

Answer (score 4):

I'm using react-native v0.59.9 with `shrinkResources true` configuration. 
It makes react-native could not find the assets.

Make sure you do not set `shrinkResources` on android build.gradle unless the new version of react-native support it later on.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using RN 0.61.2

As stated by @made-in-moon here this worked for me:

`react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/`

Comment: I'm using 61.5 and this command creates in res few folders with inside the images that I use in the app. 
If I run the app: "npx react-native run-android" with the cable connected the images are visible. Once I disconnect the cable and reopen the app on my phone, the images are not visible.

Comment: @mtoninelli I'm not aware of this issue TBH. On my device, the images are showing perfectly. Try uninstalling & making a fresh install. Let us know what worked.

Answer (score 1):

Verify whether images are in **`../res`** folder or not **`${project}/android/app/src/res`**. If not then you need to copy images in that folder. That can be done using following react command

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js \ --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle \ --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

Ideally, this happens in Android when images sizes are larger. Another way to avoid such issues at runtime is to optimize image sizes.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 14 one can also upgrade to the latest version of react-native `0.63.3`

Answer (score 0):

Check the name of the image file or try renaming.In my case, it was the name of the image. I renamed(removed '-' character) the image and it worked.