# React Native Android APK building - images in the app are not loading

Tags: react-native

When I run the app using react-native run-android app is loading fine with all images (not talking about external urls, images in the app folder). but when I generate the apk using ./gradlew assembleRelease, the apk is generating fine but with no images. I didnt see any errors when generating the apk

I deleted the .dist folder in node_modules and  have tried running the command `curl "http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android" -o "android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle"`
from this link [Android failed to load JS bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32572399/android-failed-to-load-js-bundle)

I want the apk generated should have the images

Comment: Try This. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38941436/react-native-android-static-image-is-not-showing-in-production-released-apk

Answer (score 0):

Please try with `https` instead of `http`