# React Native typescript Svg images not show in Release apk build

Tags: javascript, react-native, svg

In my app, SVG images are not displayed in release apk. I use typescript in react native Please give me a solution if it works then I accept your answer, Anyone, here with a solution for this? Thanks in Advance.

I also refer to this
[react-native build apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38941436/react-native-android-static-image-is-not-showing-in-production-released-apk)

but this is not working for me. Please help

Comment: Please provide your code block related to SVG. Also, please provide which platform causing the issue and which library are you using to render SVG. This will help us better evaluate your problem and provide you solution.

Comment: @SaachiTech  package use react-native-svg-uri  and my code  <SvgUri
                                            width="20"
                                            height="20"
                                            source={item.smallimg}
                                        /> and problem accurs in   android build

Comment: This is a known bug with Android, here is more info https://github.com/vault-development/react-native-svg-uri#known-bugs

Comment: You can find working solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/70522619/4934132

Answer (score 1):

Since OP has an issue with Android and this is a known [bug](https://github.com/vault-development/react-native-svg-uri#known-bugs) with the library OP using. Here is a workaround which works on both platform with the library

create a new file, name it Svg.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Platform } from 'react-native'
import SvgUri from 'react-native-svg-uri';
//import { SvgUri } from 'react-native-svg';
export default ({ width, height, source, fill }) => Platform.select({
    ios: () => <SvgUri width={width} height={height} source={source} fill={fill} />,
    android: () => { const SVG = source; return <SVG width={width} height={height} fill={fill} /> },
})();
```

Create another js file that holds your SVG, name it imageManager.js. Import SVG and export it like this

```
import Home from '../assets/home.svg';//Change it with your SVG path
module.exports = {
  Home
}
```

Now in any of your js where you want to display SVG, use above component like this

```
import SvgUri from './Svg';
import { Home } from './imageManager';
<SvgUri width="100%" height="35" source={ Home  } />
```

You might also need to install `react-native-svg-transformer`.
Then please update your metro.config with following

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("metro-config");

module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: { sourceExts, assetExts }
  } = await getDefaultConfig();
  return {
    transformer: {
      getTransformOptions: async () => ({
        transform: {
          experimentalImportSupport: false,
          inlineRequires: false,
        },
      }),
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer")
    },
    resolver: {
      assetExts: assetExts.filter(ext => ext !== "svg"),
      sourceExts: [...sourceExts, "svg"]
    }
  };
})();
```

This should solve the issue in the production Android. Good Luck

Comment: @HAPPYBHALODIYA ok, you did not mention that in your question. Please update your question.

Comment: I got Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: number. @SaachiTech

Comment: @HAPPYBHALODIYA Are you using expo for the test? Please post the SVG file you are trying to render?